# failing to create ACL tables using console

Tags: cakephp

i have used the cake schema create DbAcl before, succesfully at that. for some reason the output that i am now getting is not that which i require. the shell is returning some help options but will not create the aros and acos tables. help

Comment: I am typing the following in my command prompt...C:\xampp\php C:\xampp\htdocs\students\app\Console\cake schema create DbAcl

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy the path to the console folder to my environmental variables and restarted the command line. that did the trick